# Заполнение всех полей ввода

Tags: html, angular

Есть разметка:

```
<div class="scroll">
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Обложка</th>
            <th>Название</th>
            <th>Автор</th>
            <th>Год издания</th>
            <th>ISBN код</th>
            <th>Цена</th>
            <th>Количество</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let book of bookService.bookList">
            <td><img src="../../{{book.ImagePath}}" width="100" height="150"></td>
            <td>{{book.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{book.Author}}</td>
            <td>{{book.Year}}</td>
            <td>{{book.ISBN}}</td>
            <td>{{book.Price}}</td>
            <td>{{book.Count}}</td>
            <td>

                <input type="text" name="Count" [(ngModel)]="Count">
                <button class="btn btn-block btn-outline-success" (click)="onAdd(book, Count)"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Имеет вид:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в следующем: при заполнении одного `TextBox'a` заполняются все `TextBox'ы` в столбце.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно решить данную проблему? Пробовал давать уникальные имена текстовым полям и засовывать эту ячейку в `form`, но все равно не работало.

Comment: `[(ngModel)]="book.Count"`

Comment: @overthesanity Нет, это поле никак не относится к списку книг, оно должно заполняться от руки

Comment: ну так у вас модель одна, естественно апдейтится будут все поля